# How to get the number of records of a filtered rich:datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam, richdatatable

I'm using Seam and I'm displaying items from the DB using rich:datable. Knowing the number of items is straightforward, since I know the size of the list.

The problem arises when the user uses one of the filters, which is handled automatically by the rich:datatable. On that case, since it handles the code by itself, I don't know the size of the displayed list.

How can I get the number of records being displayed, when the user uses one (or more) filters?

Comment: I am also wondering where this information can be obtained, binding to a UIDataTable and calling getRowCount is not working... Which version of Richfaces are you using ? Have you found a solution ?